# How to modify visually selected block with external command?

Tags: visual-mode, external-command

I have a file that is made up of two vertical parts. On the left side, the data is already formatted and I don't want to change it. I only want to format the data on the right side. Say I have a file with lines like

```
foo=bar baz     # Neato       Junk
quux=xyzzy      # Bilbo Baggins Ring
```

with many more lines like that. I only want to modify the text to the right of the '#' character. I selected the text I want with the following expressions:

```
gg
/#
ctrl-v
G
$
```

but if I then try to modify it (say, with `:'<,'>!column -t`), it actually modifies the entirety of every line. What is the correct expression to use to only modify the visually selected parts?

Comment: You could try the [vis](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#VIS) plugin from Dr. Chip or my [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin. Both should handle it just fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can also try:

```
gg
^V
G
t#
d
:%!column -t
gg
P
```

From [`:h :visual_example`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#:visual_example):

> Currently the ":" command works on whole lines only.  When you select part of a line, doing something like ":!date" will replace the whole line.  If you want only part of the line to be replaced you will have to make a mapping for it.  In a future release ":" may work on partial lines.

See also [`:h visual-operators`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-operators) for details.