# Replace selection with output of external command

Tags: external-command, replace

Assuming I have a line in a file with `XXXX` being a placeholder I have selected via `v` as follows:

```
XXXX Some other text
```

How can I change *only* the `XXXX` with the output of an external command, such as `date +%Y%m%d`?

I got as far as

```
:'<,'>!date +\%Y\%m\%d
```

but that replaced the whole line.

Comment: Related question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8403599/filter-only-several-words-not-the-complete-line-through-an-external-command

Answer (score 18):

You could delete the text and insert the output of a command using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>-<kbd>=</kbd>:

```
CTRL-R {0-9a-z"%#*+:.-=}                                        i_CTRL-R
                Insert the contents of a register.  Between typing CTRL-R and
                the second character, '"' will be displayed to indicate that
                you are expected to enter the name of a register.
 …
                                                        i_CTRL-R_=
                        '='     the expression register: you are prompted to
                                enter an expression (see expression)
```

For the expression, you can use the [`system()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#system%28%29) function to run external commands.

After selecting the text, press `c`, then [`<c-r>=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-R_%3D) and use `system('date +%Y%m%d')` as the expression.

Comment: That adds a newline between the replaced text and the rest of the line, doesn't it?

Comment: @muk.li that's part of the output of `date`. If you try something like `system('printf %s foo')`, which doesn't output a trailing newline, you'll see there's a difference.

Comment: @muk.li if you just want the date in the text, there's the [`strftime`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#strftime%28%29) function which you can use instead of `system('date …')`. The format string is the same.

Comment: You do not need to delete selected text. You can use `"=system('date +%Y%m%d')p` on visual selection instead.

Answer (score 5):

If you put the cursor on such a line you can:

- `0` to put the cursor in the first column.
- `f` <kbd>Space</kbd> to put the cursor in the first blank.
- `i` <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd> to split the line.
- `l` to move the cursor one line up.
- `:.!date +\%Y\%m\%d` to execute the command.
- `J` to join the lines again.

From [`:h :visual_example`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#:visual_example):

> Currently the ":" command works on whole lines only.  When you select part of a line, doing something like ":!date" will replace the whole line.  If you want only part of the line to be replaced you will have to make a mapping for it.  In a future release ":" may work on partial lines.

See also [`:h visual-operators`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/visual.html#visual-operators) for details.

From [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/how-to-modify-visually-selected-block-with-external-command/6899#comment11226_6898) comment: You can also try the [vis](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#VIS) or [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin. Both should handle it just fine. (Thanks @christian-brabandt for the tip).

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary mapping for such replacements. For example:

```
:vnoremap qq c<C-R>=system('wc -c | perl -pe chomp', @")<CR><ESC>
```

Then in visual mode you can select text, type `qq` and it'll be replaced by the command output. In this example `wc -c` will process your selection, which is the `@"` parameter. `perl -pe chomp` is needed to remove a trailing  newline from the output.

Comment: Note that this solution is a wrapper around muru's answer, creating a mapping for a one time usage might not be the most efficient method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
:let @a = system('date +\%Y\%m\%d')[:-2]
:'<,'>g/XXXX/s/XXXX/\=@a/g
```

- The first line saves the output of `date` command into register a, with the ending newline removed.
- The second line globally inspect your selection and mark the lines containing `XXXX` (`g/XXXX/`), and
- replace all the instances of the `XXXX` with the content of register a (`s/XXXX/\=@a/g`)

See `:h let-@` and `:h :global` as well as the "Sublist" section in `:h list-index`

Answer (score 0):

### Plugin: [*Visual Block Commands*](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#VIS) (vis) by DrChip

Installation of `vis.vba.gz` and dependency `cecutil.vba.gz` into vim8 packpath

```
# shell brace expansion (bash >=3.0, zsh>=2.6)
$ mkdir -p ~/.vim/pack/manual/start/{vis,cecutil}
$ vim http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/vis.vba.gz
:UseVimball ~/.vim/pack/manual/start/vis
:e http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/vbafiles/cecutil.vba.gz
:UseVimball ~/.vim/pack/manual/start/cecutil
```

OP example becomes

```
:'<,'>B !date +\%Y\%m\%d
```