# How to pipe *characters* to cmd ( `:!` )

Tags: command-line, visual-mode, range

It is possible to pipe visually selected *lines* (i.e. selected with uppercase <kbd>V</kbd>) using <kbd>:</kbd>, after which I can enter a command in vim's command line,  e.g.:

```
:'<,'>!python -m base64 -d
```

I'd like to do the same for the selected *character range* (i.e. selected with lowercase <kbd>v</kbd>). Using <kbd>:</kbd> still creates a linewise range (`:'<'>`). Trying to manually provide a character range like this:

```
:`<,`>!python -m base64 -d
```

Still does not work; it outputs this:

```
E492: Not an editor command: `<`>!python -m base64 -d
```

The question: **How can I pipe visually selected characters to a system (cmd) program?**

Comment: similar question: http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/replace-selection-with-output-of-external-command

Comment: From [this](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/6898/how-to-modify-visually-selected-block-with-external-command/6899#comment11226_6898) comment: You can also try the [vis](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/#VIS) or [NrrwRgn](https://github.com/chrisbra/NrrwRgn) plugin. Both should handle it just fine. (Thanks @christian-brabandt for the tip).

Comment: Thanks @Sundeep, you're right, I have marked it as a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

You can define a function in your `.vimrc`:

```
    function! GetVisualSelection()
    let [lnum1, col1] = getpos("'<")[1:2]
    let [lnum2, col2] = getpos("'>")[1:2]
    let lines = getline(lnum1, lnum2)
    let lines[-1] = lines[-1][: col2 - (&selection == 'inclusive' ? 1 : 2)]
    let lines[0] = lines[0][col1 - 1:]
    return join(lines, "\\n")
endfunction
```

And then execute something like this:
`<C-u>exe "!echo \"" . GetVisualSelection() . "\" | python -m base64 -d"`

To give credits I took function from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6271254/1199156), only change is last line to include double backslash to make it work in shell.

Comment: This is an excellent answer, and the correct one if we *have* to use `!`. Otherwise, the answer @Sundeep has suggested (see my own answer) is much simpler and achieve the same result. Yours however will also work with block mode. Note that I have marked the question as a duplicate. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If someone looks for an answer, here is the one from [Replace selection with output of external command](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7388/replace-selection-with-output-of-external-command)

- <kbd>c</kbd> to put the visually selected text in the default (`"`") register
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> to execute a Vim command
- <kbd>=</kbd> to use the `execute` register
- `system('whatever command', @")` to pass the default register (`@"`) to the system command
- <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute the command
- <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to the normal mode

This can be remapped to a shortcut

```
vnoremap <silent> <leader>btoa c<c-r>=system('base64 --decode --wrap=0', @")<cr><esc>
```